# Maximum number of divisors in python3

Tags: python

My teacher told me write this code only with one func

```
it has to print the largest number of divisors between 20 numbers 
and if 2 number had same count of divisors print the largest one
```

I writed this but its not working.
I got errors when I only use var in functions then I fix this I see devisors are 0 .

Help me im new with python and I must use simple way .. thank you

This is my code

```
number = int(input('Enter your number: '))

def divisor(number):

    temp_1=0
    temp_2=0
    answer = 0

    for i in range(1, number+1):
        if number % i == 0:
            temp_1+=1
        if temp_1>=temp_2:
            if(number > answer):
                answer = number
            
    print(answer,temp_2)

for i in range(1,20):
    
    divisor(number)
    
    number = int(input('Enter your number: '))
print (divisor())
```

Comment: if you get error then show it in question. Don't expect that we run code to see error. And code may works correctly on our computers. Always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.

Comment: you can use `print()` to see values in variable and which part of code is executed - and you can compare it with calculations on paper. It is called `"print debuging"`

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple and beginner-friendly way to find all the divisors using one function written in python.

```
def divisors(number):

  n= 1 
  for n in range(n,number+1): 
      if (number % n == 0): 
          print(n) 
          n += 1
```

If you need to find, quite literally, the maximum amount of divisors for a number in python then this might help also.

```
def divisor(number):

  n= 1
  MaximumDivisor = []
  for n in range(n,number+1):
      if (number % n == 0):
          MaximumDivisor.append(n)
          n += 1
  print(len(MaximumDivisor))
```

Answer (score 0):

This function will return a key(the divisor) and value (the number of divisor)

```py
def max_n_divisor(list_input):
    # Create a dictionaria with dict={number: n_divisor}
    dict_test = {}
    for i in list_input:
        count = 0
        for j in range(1,i+1):
            if i/j == int(i/j):
                count += 1
        dict_test[i]=count

    # Find the max n_divisor
    key_max,value_max = list(dict_test.items())[0]
    for key,value in dict_test.items():
        if value > value_max:
            value_max=value
            key_max=key
        elif value == value_max:
            if key > key_max:
                key_max = key
    return key_max,value_max

list_in = [99, 96, 93, 86, 74, 62, 59, 55,
           51, 46, 42, 38, 38, 35, 34, 31, 29, 27, 6, 4]

print(max_n_divisor(list_in))
#(96,12)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is some optimized solution with the sieve of eratosthenes!
It can do it for 2M elements

```
maxn = 2000009
a = [1 for i in range(maxn)]
i = 2
while i < maxn:
    j = i
    while j < maxn:
        a[j] += 1
        j += i
    i += 1
from sys import stdin
n = int(stdin.readline())
_n = 0
ans = 0
for x in list(map(int, stdin.readline().split())):
    if a[x] >= a[n]:
        _n = x
        ans = max(ans, _n)
print(ans)
```